# При уменьшении зума видно много картинок фона и уменьшается текст

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Я делаю сайт и у меня такая проблема, что при уменьшении зума видно много картинок фоновых, хотя я сделал одну. Как ограничить размер сайта и чтобы такого не было?
Загрузить скриншот не могу, слишком большой размер, говорит сайт. Вот ссылка на сайт где вы сами можете удостовериться и изучить проблему [www.darkyoutube.ml](http://www.darkyoutube.ml)

Answer (score 1):

проблема довольно просто решается , нужно лишь дописать пару стилей для body.

```
body{
    background-repeat: no-repeat; //// убирает повторение картинок
    background-position: center; //// делает картинку по центру(вертикально и горизонтально)
    background-size: cover; ////// делает картинку на весь блок

}
```

Так же из-за того, что у вас слишком мало контента на странице картинка будет не на весь экран. Чтобы это исправить можно сделать body высотой на весь экран.

```
body{
   height: 100vh; ///// высота равна 100% от высоты окна браузера
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: @DarkHacker отметьте вопрос решеным